# How to make while loop in python that is reliable enough for packet generator

Tags: python, sockets, loops, networking

I'm making a packet generator and it's crucial to be able to send packets as steadily and as accurately as possible. The problem I'm having is that I send the packets using a while loop with time.sleep that is supposed to loop hundreds times/second, but since it takes additional and varying time to go through the loop it's hard to set a right sleeping time.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
while status == "1":
     try:
         s.send(message)
         data = s.recv(1500)
         status = self.clientstatus
         time.sleep(1.0 / (speed*100))
     except:
         status = "0"
```

EDIT:

Here is a working solution that I used

```
    def clientstart(self):
      self.sch = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
      self.next_time = time.time()
      self.sch.enterabs(self.next_time, 0, self.oneround, ())

      self.reset.emit()
      time.sleep(0.03)

      n = 0
      targetip = self.entry1.text()
      host = targetip
      port = 5001
      speed = int(self.entry2.text())
      self.delay = 1.0 / (speed*100)

      if targetip:
              self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
              try:
                    self.s.connect((host,port))
              except:
                    self.err1.emit(1)
                    n = n+1
              openfile = open('1024')
              self.message = openfile.read()
              self.clientstatus = "1"
              status = self.clientstatus
              self.buttonswitch("2")
              n = n+1
              self.nn = 1
              t = threading.Thread(target = self.temp)
              t.setDaemon(True)
              t.start()
              self.err1.emit(2)
              self.sch.run()

              if n == 1:
                    self.err1.emit(4)
              elif n == 4:
                    self.err1.emit(0)
              self.s.close()
              self.buttonswitch("3")
      else:
              self.err1.emit(3)

    def oneround(self):
      try:
        self.s.send(self.message)
        status = self.clientstatus
        self.nn += 1
        if status == '1':
            self.next_time += self.delay
            self.sch.enterabs(self.next_time, 0, self.oneround, ())
      except:
        pass
```

using self with socket might cause some problems in the future though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the soundest ways to schedule periodic events, as close to regularly as a system that's of course not real-time will allow, is the `sched` module documented at https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html .

For your use case, I'd try:

```
import sched, time
sch = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

delay = 1.0 / (speed*100)
next_time = time.time()

def oneround():
    try:
        s.send(message)
        data = s.recv(1500)
        status = self.clientstatus
        if status == '1':
            next_time += delay
            sch.enterabs(next_time, 0, oneround, ())
    except:
        pass

sch.enterabs(next_time, 0, oneround, ())

sch.run()
```

This will stay as close to one event every `1.0 / (speed*100)` seconds as feasible -- if one event was delayed (we're not in a real hard time environment so the operating system can cause unpredictable delays) the next one will be scheduled nearer in the future, &c.  The implied loop ends when nothing more is entered in `sch`.

Comment: I'd like to test this but I have to create the socket outside the function oneround(). That means I'd need to pass socket, delay and message as arguments and then wouldn't be able to call the function again with sch.enterabs(). Is there a way around this (like making the arguments class wide) or should I make the server in oneround()?

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly after I got it right. Thank you alot. I'll add the working code here